# Image not coming up from .EAR deployed on WebSphere 8.5

Tags: html, jsp, build, websphere, websphere-8

In STS, I have created an enterprise project(exported as MyEar.EAR) containing .WAR( i.e. MyWar.war)  module.

I deployed it into WebSphere 8.5.

After deployment overall structure of the build is as follows:

MyEar.ear\MyWar.war\public

MyEar.ear\MyWar.war\public\img

MyEar.ear\MyWar.war\public\img\logo.jpg

MyEar.ear\MyWar.war\MyJsp.jsp

Now, the issue is this that Image:"logo.jpg" is not appearing into "MyJsp.jsp" (below is the code).

`<img src="./public/img/logo.jpg"></img>`-----Please Consider MyEar.ear\MyWar.war as the .WAR context.

Shall be thankful for the help?

Comment: Are you accessing WAS directly or via http server? What is link in the browser to your MyJsp.jsp page that is working?

Comment: Via http server. WAS is installed locally. following is the link to MyJsp.jsp, http://localhost:9080/MyWar/MyJsp.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have `ibm-web-ext.xml` file in WEB-INF, and if you have there entry:

```
<enable-file-serving value="true"/>
```

Your image should be accessible by the following link:

```
 http://localhost:9080/MyWar/public/img/logo.jpg
```